# Parse xml doc on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to parse an xml doc.
Following is a code snippet:

```
//Following is on receiving the xml doc  
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function()  
{
  if(self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && self.xmlHttpReq.status == 200)
  {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
      xmlDoc = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
      var reqst = new RegExp("<d0>0"); //This could only get binary value  
      //How to parse in IE??  

     }
     else  // Moz, Chrome  
     {
       xmlDoc = self.xmlHttpReq.responseXML;  
       xmldat1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('d0')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;  
       xmldat2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('d1')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;  
     }
  }
```

The above parsing works well for mozilla and chrome, but for IE how can I do the parsing?
Note: I can't use any jquery technique.

Comment: I would expect the code you use for Mozilla and Chrome to work fine in IE too

Comment: No, IE throws "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this particular line when parsing for IE5 and IE6:

`xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");`

Check this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

This might help you understand better.